# FIX Protocol Testing on Jmeter?

Tags: api, rest, jmeter, fix-protocol

Hello Everyone I just want to ask is there's a way we can execute FIX Protocol testing using Jmeter?  Currently were using a tool and I just want to convert using Jmeter. Your response is highly appreciated. Thankyou

Current Tool:

[image]

Note: The Request data uses also the JSON format

Expected Result: I want to convert this request/response via Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing plugins, however you can use a Java client library like [QuickFIX/J](https://www.quickfixj.org/) and write the code for sending messages using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/)

Code examples can be found in the [user manual](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/), here is an example for [sending the message](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/sending_messages.html) just in case:

```
import quickfix.*;

Message message = new Message();

// BeginString
message.getHeader().setField(new StringField(8, "FIX.4.2"));

// SenderCompID
message.getHeader().setField(new StringField(49, "TW"));

// TargetCompID, with enumeration
message.getHeader().setField(new StringField(56, "TARGET"));

// MsgType
message.getHeader().setField(new CharField(35, 'F'));

// OrigClOrdID
message.setField(new StringField(41, "123"));

// ClOrdID
message.setField(new StringField(11, "321"));

// Symbol
message.setField(new StringField(55, "LNUX"));

// Side, with value enumeration
message.setField(new CharField(54, Side.BUY));

// Text
message.setField(new StringField(58, "Cancel My Order!"));

Session.sendToTarget(message);
```

Alternatively you can create [your own plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices) to make scripts creation and execution easier and faster